# How to avoid line breaks within |...| in Emacs

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, how can I avoid line breaks within |...| when using M-q (fill-paragraph)?

In https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/gnu.emacs.help/fill-nobreak-predicate/gnu.emacs.help/qNuZZjQnsww/99oJ1fb4OSUJ I found the following solution for [[...]], but it doesn't work when the open and close delimiters are the same:

```
(defun fill-open-link-nobreak-p ()
  "Don't break a line after an unclosed \"[[link \"."
  (save-excursion
    (skip-chars-backward " ")
    (let ((opoint (point))
          spoint inside)
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (setq spoint (point)))
       (when (re-search-backward "\\[\\[" spoint t)
        ;; (message "found") (sit-for 2)
        (unless (re-search-forward "\\]\\]" opoint t)
          (setq inside t)))
      inside)))

(add-to-list 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'fill-open-link-nobreak-p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(defun odd-number-of-pipes-this-paragraph-so-far ()
  (oddp (how-many "|" (save-excursion (backward-paragraph) (point)) (point))))

(add-to-list 'fill-nobreak-predicate 'odd-number-of-pipes-this-paragraph-so-far)
```

Comment: You're welcome, but you can really demonstrate your thanks by accepting my answer (clicking on the empty check mark to the left)...